# Trouble with C Code for Case-Insensitive Substring Removal in a String

Tags: arrays, c, string, substring, case-sensitive

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int erase_once(char *input_string, const char *substring, int case_sensitive) {
    size_t string_length = strlen(input_string);
    size_t substring_length = strlen(substring);

    if (string_length < substring_length || substring_length == 0) return 0;

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < string_length - substring_length + 1; i++) {
        int match_found = 1;

        for (size_t j = i; j < i + substring_length; j++) {
            if ((case_sensitive == 0 &&
                 tolower(input_string[j]) != tolower(substring[j-i])) ||
                input_string[j] != substring[j-i]) {
                match_found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!match_found) continue;

        for (; i < string_length - substring_length; i++) {
            input_string[i] = input_string[i + substring_length];
        }
        input_string[i] = '\0';

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int erase(char *input_string, const char *substring, int case_sensitive) {
    int count;
    for (count = 0; erase_once(input_string, substring, case_sensitive); count++);
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    char main_string[] = "abcdef cde AbCDE";
    const char *substring_to_erase = "abc";

    erase(main_string, substring_to_erase, 0);
    printf("%s\n", main_string);

    return 0;
}
```

I tryed to make it case sensitive by putting the variable int case_sensitive; and when that wariable is 0 it is not sensitive and when it is 1 it is case sensitive so for example:
for input "abcdef cde AbCDE" and substring "abc" if it is 1 it should return
-"def cde AbCDE";
and for the same input and case_sensitive set to 0
it should return "def cde DE"
another example is for string
xYXyXYXY and substring xy and sensitive set to 0 it should return
an empty string

but it doesnt, can you help me find the mistake?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please show the outputs you get for the described input.

Comment: @eminbihh, What result expected for `"ababa"`, `"aba"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the result is "ba"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the task into smaller bits

```
int strneq(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n, int cs)
{
    char c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
    while(n-- && *s1 && *s2)
    {
        if(cs)
        {
            c1 = *s1;
            c2 = *s2;
        }
        else
        {
            c1 = tolower(*s1);
            c2 = tolower(*s2);
        }
        if(c1 != c2) break;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return !(c1 == c2);
}

char *mystrstr(const char *s, const char *find, int cs)
{
    size_t slen = strlen(s);
    size_t flen = strlen(find);
    char *result = NULL;
    if(slen >= flen)
    for(size_t index = 0; index <= slen - flen; index++)
    {
        if(!strneq(s + index, find, slen - index  + 1, cs))
        {
            result = (char *)(s + index);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char *strrem(char *haystack, const char *needle, int cs)
{
    size_t nlen = strlen(needle);
    size_t hlen = strlen(haystack);
    char *current;
    while((current = mystrstr(haystack, needle, cs)))
    {
        while((*current = *(current + nlen))) current++;
    }
    return haystack;
}

int main(void)
{
    char h[] = "abcdef cde AbCDE";
    char *n = "abc";

    printf("'%s'\n", strrem(h,n,0));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M7bh8Pq7a

Comment: but it still doesnt work for instances like this
string 'ABC  ABcAbC' substring 'abc'
it should return '  ', but it returns '  AbC'
or for 'xXxXYYyy' substring 'xy' it should also return a empty string but it doesnt

Comment: @eminbihh I did tiny mistake. Amended the answer

Comment: Thank alot for the help it works now :)))))

Answer (score 2):

you have just forget to check if case_sensitive==1, other wise it will always the second half of your 'if condition' will be checked and considered.
this is the line you need to edit

```
if ((case_sensitive == 0 &&
                 tolower(input_string[j]) != tolower(substring[j-i])) ||
                (case_sensitive == 1 &&
                input_string[j] != substring[j-i]))
```

note: you have complicated the solution too much, and your code isn't clean enough, those tricks will help you to identify any problem and make it easy for you to debug

Answer (score 0):

**Everything inside 1 function:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int erase(char* input_string, const char* substring, int case_sensitive) {
    int len1 = strlen(input_string),
        len2 = strlen(substring);

    if (len1 < len2 || len1 < 0) return 0;

    int eraseCount = 0,
        N = len1 - len2 + 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N;) {
        int found = 1;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
            char c1 = input_string[i + j], c2 = substring[j];
            
            if(( case_sensitive && tolower(c1) != tolower(c2)) || //case_sensitive == 0 - false, otherwise true (any value)
               (!case_sensitive && c1 != c2)) {
                    found = 0;
                    i += j;
                    break;
            } 
        }
        
        if(found) {
            eraseCount++;
            
            for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
                input_string[j] = input_string[j + len2]; //move left
            for(int j = N + len2 - 2; j >= N - 1; j--)
                input_string[j] = 0; //removed
            
            N -= len2;
        } else i++;
    }
    
    return eraseCount;
}

void test1(){
    char main_string[] = "abcdef cde AbCDE";
    const char *substring_to_erase = "abc";
    erase(main_string, substring_to_erase, 0);
    printf("String: \"%s\"\n", main_string);
}

void test2(){
    char main_string[] = "xYXyXYXY";
    const char *substring_to_erase = "xy";
    erase(main_string, substring_to_erase, 1);
    printf("String: \"%s\"\n", main_string);
}

int main(void) {
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
String: "def cde AbCDE"
String: ""


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: It can be done in many ways, just like yours but i have a series of tests that it has to pass and couldnt manage to find one that passes them all